# Why is X-Powered-By Header not disabled after using helmet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-modules

I've installed Helmet on my Express app and integrated it in my app.js using

```
app.use(helmet());
const helmet = require('helmet');
```

When I restarted my app, the X-Powered-by header, however, still is not disabled. `app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());` is not working either.
When looking at my `npm list` in the console I see helmet@4.6.0 appearing.
My goal is to use other functions from helmet as well, so simply doing `app.disable('x-powered-by');` is no option..

Answer (score 1):

Plain **ExpressJS** should also do.

```
app.disable('x-powered-by')
```

useful link: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html

Comment: Right, but [the docs clearly say](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-helmet) Helmet will do that (if you use `hidePoweredBy`). the question appears to be: Why isn't it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I was wondering, too. And I might want to use other functionalities of helmet, too..

Comment: thanks for editing, I wondered incase you're looking for framework approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/blob/780c34a0275198ca7eba9a729de213af95301a22/middlewares/x-powered-by/README.md), it looks like you need to import and call the function:

```
const hidePoweredBy = require("hide-powered-by");
app.use(hidePoweredBy());
```

([This test](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/blob/14941535c001d99835aa358522f950259db43157/test/index.test.ts) shows us that there used to be a config option, too, but it's deprecated.)

But those docs also say:

> Note: if you're using Express, you don't need this middleware and can just do this:
>
> `app.disable("x-powered-by");`

Comment: If I require and use the `hidePoweredBy()` like you suggested my app crashes saying `Error: Cannot find module 'hide-powered-by'`

Comment: @codingbudgie - That just means you don't have the module installed. But again: There's basically no reason for it. Just use the string from the Express docs.